# SELinux policys keeping Tomcat from starting

Tags: tomcat, selinux, systemctl, rhel8

On a newly built Oracle Linux 8 server i added a drive and file system, then put put Apache Tomcat on that file system via the tarball. Now when starting Tomcat via a services file, I get an error saying Tomcat has not started, and my journalctl file shows the following:

### Apr 04 09:53:17 t-einv systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://support.oracle.com

### -- Unit tomcat.service has failed.

-- The result is failed.
Apr 04 09:53:17 t-einv setroubleshoot[2924]: AnalyzeThread.run(): Cancel pending alarm
Apr 04 09:53:17 t-einv setroubleshoot[2924]: SELinux is preventing /usr/lib/systemd/systemd from execute_no_trans access on the file /u01/tomcat/bin/startup.sh. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 97dddf7a-4f8a-4>
Apr 04 09:53:17 t-einv setroubleshoot[2924]: SELinux is preventing /usr/lib/systemd/systemd from execute_no_trans access on the file /u01/tomcat/bin/startup.sh.

```
                                         *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                         If you believe that systemd should be allowed execute_no_trans access on the startup.sh file by default.
                                         Then you should report this as a bug.
                                         You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                         Do
                                         allow this access for now by executing:
                                         # ausearch -c '(artup.sh)' --raw | audit2allow -M my-artupsh
                                         # semodule -X 300 -i my-artupsh.pp
```

Apr 04 09:53:17 t-einv setroubleshoot[2924]: AnalyzeThread.run(): Set alarm timeout to 10

ruunig ls -FlasZ on the tomcate/bin directory shows the following selinux policies on startup.sh

unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0   1904 Apr  3 09:27 startup.sh*

Any ideas on how wo change the policy permanently to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

For security sake, webservers cannot execute a writable file with the default selinux policy.

If it is needed (for cached compiled files for example), run `setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1`.

If it isn't, remove the write permissions on the files you need tomcat to execute. (`/u01/tomcat/bin/startup.sh` here)

Also, I find it easier to understand denials with `audit2allow -a` command.